# Trying to convert input string to integer in Swift

Tags: string, swift, int

I am trying to write a program that takes a number input from user and stores it into a string, then i am trying to convert that string to integer for further use. Whenever i convert it, it displays nil for the integer value but will print the input when kept as a string. Here is my code so far. This is my first time trying to write in swift.

```
import Foundation

func input() -> String{
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
}


print("What is a number: ")

let user: String? = input()
print("You typed: " + user!)

var num = Int(user!)
print("Your number was" ,(num))
```

Comment: What if your input is not number? Or you just assume the input to be number

Comment: `user` contains a newline character at the end, that's why your conversion to `Int` is failing.

Comment: how do i get rid of the newline character

Comment: Copy every character to a new string, until you find the newline, then stop copying. Return the new string.

Comment: How would i go about doing that, I started looking a swift today so I am clueless as to how I should copy until a certain character shows up.

Comment: @JordonInman: I'd suggest going through a Swift tutorial. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for learning how to write in your chosen language. Work on easier problems until you can figure this one out, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The `Int` function returns an **optional** integer, so if your string can't be converted it will return nil. If you assign it a value that it can convert, you'll get the result you're looking for:

```
let user: String = "5"
var num = Int(user)

if let num = num {
    print("Your number was \(num)")
} else {
    print("Your number is nil")
}
```

Also, your `input` function is returning a `String`, but you're defining the `user` variable as an optional `String?`

Answer (score 0):

After searching around and trying different things, I was able to do exactly what I wanted after doing...

```
var user = input()
var newString = user.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
```